# WordPress - Advanced Custom Fields Clashing With Posts In Static Page

Tags: wordpress

I have a static page that has an Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) 'repeater' region in it and some code to pull in some custom posts.

I have this code at the top of the page.

```
<?php get_header(); the_post(); query_posts('post_type=team_profiles') ?>
```

If left like this, I see my posts but not the data from the ACFs.  If I take out the following section:

```
query_posts('post_type=team_profiles')
```

I see the ACF fields but not the post data.

My questions are firstly why this is happening and secondly how I can have them both on the same page?

Code for ACF and POSTS in my static page is as follows:

**ACF Repeater Field**

```
    <?php if( get_field('about_sections') ): ?>

    <?php while( has_sub_field('about_sections') ): ?>

    <div class="asset image">

    <?php the_sub_field('about_section'); ?>

    </div> <!-- asset image -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

**POSTS**

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content-single-team-profile', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the complete source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the main query is being overridden when you call get_posts(). You can either:

- Call the get_posts() **AFTER** you get all you need from the static page (the repeater field values, etc).

OR

- Call wp_reset_query() **BEFORE** trying to get values from the static page. This will set the original parameters for that page's main query.

Take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Those are simple solutions. More complex and better ones would involve creating a WP_Query object and iterate it's posts instead of relying on global variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, makes perfect sense.  I actually thought I may have posted too much code.  I have noted this for future questions.